Is balancing imbalanced validation set for retraining model after hyperparameter tuning required?
The following are basic steps to modelling, but would like to ask in the case of imbalanced data, is balancing of train dataset required when retraining model on train + validation set after hyperparameter tuning?
Prior to modelling, data should be split into train set, validation set and test set.
Resampling should be applied to train set to balance this train set. Resampling should not be applied to validation set and test set so that they are representative of the true population. In other words, validation set and test set will be imbalanced.
After training model on (balanced) train set and tuning on validation set, I get the best hyperparameters. With these hyperparameters, retrain the model on (balanced) train set + validation set.
Here's what I have question with. Should balancing be applied to validation set as well because it will be part of the dataset used for retraining the model?
